# Get all images in post and comments like Twitter before post title

Tags: posts, images, comments, post-thumbnails, comments-template

I want to know if it's possible to get all the `images` that are in a post and his `comments`, make them a thumbnail and put it before (or in a sidebar or something) the post title to show, just like `Twitter` does. Of course it would be wonderful if you navigate to the comment where it was inserted if you click on a `thumbnail`, but that's something for later.

Is this possible, if so, how?

PS: I am not using a plugin, I just want to know if it can search for all the `<img>` tags and make them thumbnails out of no where...

Answer (score 0):

Getting all the images from the post, and adding them to the top of the post is relatively easy. You can do something like this: (Note, this is just a code example. I'm not 100% what you are looking for. Hopefully this is enough to get you started.)

```
function getImagesInThisPost() {
    global $post, $posts;
    //find all the <img>'s in the post
    $output = preg_match_all(
        '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', 
        $post->post_content, //from the post content
        $matches
    );

    //loop throuhg all the images we found, and put them on the page
    foreach($matches[1] as $single){
        echo "<img src=\"{$single}\">";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, appreciated, but what about the images in comments? Can you get them too? That was the question actually =))

Comment: Besides, it doesn't work. I have images, but it does not put them on top of the title. Actually, it does nothing...

Comment: As I said, my example is merrily a starting point. It is not a completed solution. 

You're calling <?php getImagesInThisPost(); ?> in you're single.php or sidebar, correct?

Comment: Yes, I tried it in `single.php`, but nothing happened.